# error[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $translateMissingTranslationHandlerLogProvider <-

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate, grunt-contrib-uglify

Getting following error in `angularjs:~1.6.0` app while using `angular-translate:^2.15.2`, `translate-loader-static-files:^2.15.2` and `grunt-contrib-uglify:^0.7.0`:

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   $translateMissingTranslationHandlerLogProvider <-
>   $translateMissingTranslationHandlerLog
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24translateMissingTranslationHandlerLogProvider%20%3C-%20%24translateMissingTranslationHandlerLog

After applying `translate-cloak` translation keys flicker is gone and app is working smoothly **BUT It throws the same error mentioned above when run as `grunt server:dist`**

**Is it due to grunt uglyfying process? Any possible suggested fixes?**

How It is used inside app.js:

```
function translateFn($translateProvider) {
        $translateProvider
        .useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: 'translations/',
            suffix: '.json'
        })
        .useMissingTranslationHandlerLog();
    }
function runFn(SomeService, $translate) {
        SomeService.getData()
            .then(function () {
                $translate.use(some_data.defaults.locale);
            });
        });
    }

 ng.module('myApp', [
        'ui.router',
        .......
        'pascalprecht.translate',
        .....
    ])
    .config(configFn)
    .config(translateFn)
    .run(runFn);
```

Comment: Could you post an example of how you are injecting it?

Comment: @ProfessorAllman please see the post now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed the `angular-translate-handler-log` dependency as [stated on the docs](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/16_error-handling)?

Comment: Now it is giving warnings at first load like ... `Translation for auth.login doesn't exist`, these translations actually exist how can we get rid of warnings too?

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon This is because you are using `.useMissingTranslationHandlerLog()`. You can remove that line and the dependency, if you don't want the warnings.

Comment: that makes sense but it was bit confusing also in dev vs production builds

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [inline array annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#module-methods) with run to tell the dependency injector what to inject so that it does not matter if the function arguments get garbled up by a minifier

```
.run(["SomeService","$translate",runFn]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> bower install angular-translate-handler-log dependency -S